# Writing & Reading Text file

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I am developing MVVM CROSS Platform application, While user login we need to save some information about the user.

Is it possible to save some string data's for global use in application? if not, how to write Text file and read the contents of the text file in MVVM Core. 
Kindly suggest and provide a sample to work on this.

Comment: If the 4 answers in http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/26872/#Comment_26872 didn't help you, then I don't know what will.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I agree with Stuart. Storing data IS platform dependend, so you might issue the request in the Core part, but somewhere along the path a native function is actually handling it.

If you spent days to find this out even with the hints, I will help you a bit further:

In Core, create an interface named IUserLogin with the method StoreLogin(String name, String pwd).

```
public interface IUSerLogin {
   void StoreLogin(String name, String pwd);
}
```

Do something like this:

```
var loginthingy = Mvx.Resolve<IUSerLogin>();
loginthiny.StoreLogin("Mr. X", "Secret");
```

In the touch part, create a class UserLoginTouch : IUserLogin with this function, storing the info in the secure data storage (option 5 not mentioned before :) ).

```
public class UserLoginTouch : IUserLogin {
   public void StoreLogin(String name, String pwd) {
      // store the data
   }
}
```

In this touch project, register the UserLogin a IUserLogin:

```
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IUserLogin>(new UserLogin());
```

Hope this helps you further.